# Errors in oop concept

Tags: php, oop

Can any body help me to solve the errors in this code (even it have syntax errors);

```
class SomeClass
{
  protected $_someMember;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->_someMember = 5;
  }

  public static function getSomethingStatic() {
    return $this->_someMember * 10;
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot access instance's fields in the static method.

Comment: I think you mean OOP (Object Orientated Programming) right?

Comment: In a static method, there's no `$this`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `$this` in static context because you have no instance.

### PHP 5.3+ Code

```
<?php

class SomeClass {

  protected $property;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->property = 5;
  }

  protected static function getInstance() {
    return new static();
  }

  public static function getSomethingStatic() {
    return static::getInstance()->property * 10;
  }

}
```

### Pre PHP 5.3 Code

```
<?php

class SomeClass {

  protected $property;

  public function __construct() {
    $this->property = 5;
  }

  protected static function getInstance() {
    return new SomeClass();
  }

  public static function getSomethingStatic() {
    return self::getInstance()->property * 10;
  }

}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `new SomeClass`? and `self::getInstance()`?

Comment: `static` is a very special keyword that is used for late static binding, a feature introduced in PHP 5.3. Check it out, pretty powerful and awesome: http://php.net/language.oop5.late-static-bindings

Comment: In PHP 5.3+ `static` adheres to class hierarchy.

Comment: Nice feature, although the keyword they chose is confusing -- `static` actually references the _dynamic_ class, but it's used _in_ static methods.

Comment: Personally I think it makes perfect sense. `self` always revers to the current class and `static` goes along with the feature name (late **static** binding) and always refers to the current instance.